# Unstable result of json decoder

Tags: go

I am trying out `json.Decoder` and got something strange happening. The same code will NOT produce consistent result. Sometimes it works fine; sometimes it errors: `not at beginning of value` from calling `Decode`.

```
func main() {
    simpleRequest()
}

type FxPair struct {
    CurrencyCodeA int     `json:"currencyCodeA"`
    CurrencyCodeB int     `json:"currencyCodeB"`
    Date          int     `json:"date"`
    RateBuy       float64 `json:"rateBuy"`
    RateSell      float64 `json:"rateSell"`
    RateCross     float64 `json:"rateCross"`
}

func simpleRequest() {
    res, err := http.Get("https://api.monobank.ua/bank/currency")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(res.Body)
    _, err = decoder.Token() // read the opening square bracket
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var pair FxPair
    for decoder.More() {
        err := decoder.Decode(&pair)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pair) // process a pair
    }
    _, err = decoder.Token() // read the closing square bracket
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the data you're getting back. I expect that sometimes you get an unexpected response. Maybe an empty value, or maybe just some message telling you there was a problem.

Comment: The API returns `{"errorDescription":"Too many requests"}` if you call it too frequently.

Comment: ah right, that explains it. I was like going mad as couldn't figure out what I did wrong.